# React syntax for setting checkbox ref and checking checkbox state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I have a React component which is outputting a list of checkboxes. I'm trying to set a ref for each checkbox with an ID which is pulled from the handleChange function. I would like to name the ref "id - checkbox" using the id variable which is being successfully collected by networkService:

```
networkService = ({id, label, service_state, active_path = [], z_end = []} = {}) => (
<tr>
  <td>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" ref="REF HERE WITH id-checkbox" onChange={() => this.handleChange(`${id}`)} />
    </form>
  </td>      
</tr>
```

)

I have tried numerous iterations of `${id} - checkbox` as in ref=`${id} - checkbox` but am getting errors.

Furthermore, in another function I need to check the state of that checkbox via the ref, and again the syntax is beyond me. Here is the function:

```
 handleChange = (id) => {

     if (this.refs.CHECKBOX REF HERE.checked) {
```

The id is coming successfully from the onChange call shown above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not create a react element to wrap the checkbox, put your `handleChange` code in there, then use [event bubbling](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/event-bubbling/) to keep the container state up-to-date?  **EDIT**: Or just use the `onChange` prop exposed by React on the `<input>` to set a callback with `this` bound to the `<input>`’s DOM object (ie. no need for refs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
networkService = ({id, label, service_state, active_path = [], z_end = []} = {}) => (
<tr>
  <td>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox" ref={id+"-checkbox"} onChange={() => this.handleChange(id)} />
    </form>
  </td>      
</tr>


handleChange = id => {
let refName=id+"-checkbox"
     if (this.refs[refName].checked) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I appreciate it so much!

Comment: It did Roopak I SO appreciate it. I just accepted your answer.